# Blender 2.80beta - A tutorial to animate character in Blender and export it to Unity

Tags: animation

can you tell me a video or written tutorial to create a 3D character animation in Blender 2.80 beta and then export it as .fbx for Unity 2018.3.7?

I tried starting with a character downloaded from Mixamo (only the tpose) and then imported to Blender 2.80beta, so I tried to create the desired keyframe (in Blender it seems to be OK), but when I export it to Unity as .fbx, I don't I know why but the animation is not the same as that of Blender (the arms remain always extended along the shoulders and only part of the arm moves). The animation I wanted to create is that of the character who stretches his right arm to open a door.

Comment: Blender Stack Exchange is not the right platform to ask for full-blown tutorials, especially if there are already tons on youtube about that topic. Right now, most of them are for Blender 2.79, but they are easily adaptable to Blender 2.80. An appropriate question for BSE would be "I watched this tutorial and on <time> he does this <action>. The tutorial is for Blender 2.7 x and I don't know how I would do this in Blender 2.80."

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Blender StackExchange is not suited for full-blown tutorials about rigging and exporting characters to game engines.